# Simple MySQL View made up of aggregated data from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Trying to make a simple view that keeps totals together in one row. The trick here is that I want to get these totals from multiple tables.

This way I can just select that one row to get totals for a bunch of stuff I want to keep track of.

So far I can't get this to work and most of the posts on this sort of thing have to do with joins.

```
CREATE VIEW stats AS
  select COUNT(DISTINCT publisher.name) as totalPublisher,
  select COUNT(DISTINCT series.name) as totalSeries
 From
  publisher,
  series
```

Comment: Consider whether you really need a view at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries in the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE VIEW stats AS
  select (select COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) from publisher p) as totalPublisher,
         (select COUNT(DISTINCT s.name) from series s) as totalSeries;
```

Note:  It is quite possible that the names are distinct in the tables.  If so, it is more efficient to do:

```
CREATE VIEW stats AS
  select (select count(*) from publisher p) as totalPublisher,
         (select count(*) from series s) as totalSeries;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew this should be easy

Answer (score 1):

> […] simple view that keeps totals together in one row […]

What you describe is not simple though; it involves counting totals of different sets of records. That is, of necessity, a complex query bringing together different sets of records.

You are correct that a join is a good way to do this (one reason is that it tells the RDBMS what result you want and not how to get it). But in the specific example you give, there is apparently no correlation between the values you're attempting to bring together in one row.

So one other way to do it:

```sql
CREATE VIEW stats AS
SELECT
    COUNT (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM publisher) AS total_publisher,
    COUNT (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM series) AS total_series
```